# How to create a Button Click Counter in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel. Currently, I am trying to create a button that when clicked, adds one value to the name, or $_POST value.

In vanilla PHP, I can do so with $_SESSIONs:

```
session_start();

// if counter is not set, set to zero
if(!isset($_SESSION['counter'])) {
    $_SESSION['counter'] = 0;
}

// if button is pressed, increment counter
if(isset($_POST['button'])) {
    ++$_SESSION['counter'];
}    

// reset counter
if(isset($_POST['reset'])) {
    $_SESSION['counter'] = 0;
}

?>

<form method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="counter" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['counter']; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="Counter" />
    <input type="submit" name="reset" value="Reset" />
    <br/><?php echo $_SESSION['counter']; ?>
</form>
```

However, I don't know how to do this in Larvel. Is there any documentation on how to do such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to do it with Laravel. One of them is the following:

After sending a ([GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods)/[POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29)) request when a user clicked the desired button.

You can get whatever you send through the `request()` helper function, so inside a simple controller we can have:

```php
request()->session()->increment('count');
```

There isn't any need for using the `request()` method and sessions can be accessed directly by the `session()` helper function (or Session Facade).

Also, showing the result on a simple `blade.php` page could be like below:

```php
@if(Session::has('count'))
<span>
  {{ Session::get('count')}}
</span>
@endif
```

You can read more about how Laravel deals with sessions at *[Incrementing & Decrementing Session Values](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/session##incrementing-and-decrementing-session-values)*.

Comment: Thank you. How Can I then display that value into the view? Could I use a simple get() request?

Comment: Yes, there many handful functions like: `session()->get('key')` or even `push()` and `forget()`. I have updated my answer to do that!